# Is this possible to change a single column in `dplyr` without reusing its name and without `across`?

Tags: r, dplyr, across

Is this possible to change a single column in `dplyr` without reusing its name and without `across` ?

```r
library(dplyr)

# The two following methods works

mtcars %>% 
  mutate(cyl = cyl * 2)
# Drawback : the name of the column is repeated

mtcars %>% 
  mutate(across(cyl, ~ . * 2))
# Drawback : across is used
```

Can one achieve this without repeating `cyl` or without using `across` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using `mutate_at`:

```
mtcars %>% 
  mutate_at("cyl", ~ . * 2)
```

But you have to put `cyl` in quotation marks.

Comment: I can't accept this answer since `mutate_at` is superseded by `across`